# Automatically call base method prior the derived one

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class:

```
abstract class ClassPlugin
{

    public ClassPlugin(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
            GuiType = _guyType;
    }

    public eGuiType GuiType;

    protected void Notify(bool b)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseAction()
    {
        Notify(false);
    }
}
```

and then I have some derived classes:

```
class ClassStartWF : ClassPlugin
{

    public ClassStartWF(eGuiType _guyType) : base(_guyType) { }

    public event delegate_NoPar OnStartWorkFlow_Ok;

    public void Action()
    {
        Notify(true);
        RaiseAction(eEventType.OK);
    }

    public new void RaiseAction(eEventType eventType)
    {
            base.RaiseAction();<--------------------

            if (OnStartWorkFlow_Ok == null)
                MessageBox.Show("Event OnStartWorkFlow_Ok null");
            else
                OnStartWorkFlow_Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

now in the raise action I have to call before the base.RaiseAction() method but that can be forgotten. Is there a way to automatically call the base method (and do some actions there ) before the derived method is called?

Comment: Why are you using `new` instead of *overriding* `RaiseAction`? That's an odd approach.

Comment: Yep sorry not aware of it. Editing

Comment: @Jon Skeet: On closer inspection the asker doesn't appear to be overriding anything at all. The base method has no params and the derived one does. The code doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: @BoltClock: Indeed, it's all somewhat broken. I've answered the overall thrust of the question, but ignored the sample which is odd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard solution to this is to use the *template method* pattern:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    // Note: this is *not* virtual.
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Do some work here
        SomeMethodImpl();
        // Do some work here
    }

    protected abstract void SomeMethodImpl();
}
```

Then your derived class just overrides `SomeMethodImpl`. Executing `SomeMethod` will always execute the "pre-work", then the custom behaviour, then the "post-work".

(In this case it's not clear how you want your `Notify`/`RaiseEvent` methods to interact, but you should be able to adapt the example above appropriately.)